# Can a global function take a block argument?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm writing a function that implements the [Secant Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) for a math utility library.

I'd really like to call the function with a syntax like:

```
double rootSecantMethod((double (^)(double))f, double x1, double x2, double xtol);
```

Where the `f` block implements the function being solved.

This is a "global function" in that it lives outside of an Objective-C class. I'm not sure if this is the correct term, but I don't want to call it a "C function" since it's being compiled with objc support.

Is there a way to pass a block parameter to a function that lives outside of a class, or does the compiler not support this?

Comment: Have you tried it? What problems did you run into?

Comment: Won't compile, the compiler complains "expected ')'".

Comment: it is actually same as function pointer syntax, just need to replace `*` to `^`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're placing the argument name in the incorrect place:

```
double rootSecantMethod(double (^f)(double), double x1, double x2, double xtol);
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Guess this should be another entry on http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/

Comment: For completeness, it can also be declared with `double rootSecantMethod(double (^f)(double x), ...` to give the function argument a default name